# Python websocket, is there a way to intercept a request made by another user?

Tags: python, websocket

I was playing with [mobti](https://mobti.me/example), and I noticed that when I add an user what I'm really doing is sending a json with that user. See follow example.

Json in the request.

```
{"type":"mob:update","mob":[{"id":"v63ghnghgn8","name":"test2"},{"id":"qlxy16bl9q","name":"test 1"},{"id":"zxu28bb3ar","name":"test4"},{"id":"03kys4hqrjmm","name":"test 5"},{"id":"w9osegszlzm","name":"test 3"},{"id":"od6hattxo3","name":"test6"},{"id":"d972agvwux","name":"test 7"},{"id":"y65txgk19p","name":"example stackoverflow"}]}
```

So I was able to do an script in python to send a long update with a lot of users.

```
url = "wss://mobti.me/example"
ws = create_connection(url)
ws.send(json.dumps(data))
result =  ws.recv()
print (result)
ws.close()
```

Being `data` a big json with a lot of names.

So now, here's de question, I was wondering if another user send a request with a new data, could I intercept that request? and how? I'm interested in intercepting the request and sending a new one. (It doesn't matter if I can't reject their request). Notice that this website isn't mine, so I can't intercept that request from inside (and that's not what I'm looking for)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's called a Man In the Middle Attack I believe.

Comment: @LMC As far as I know to accomplish a MITM attack I'd need to be in the same network, isn't it? I ain't trying to intercept their whole network requests but the ones sent to the websocket. I thought that maybe because of the concept I had in my mind about what a websocket is I could intercept it from anywhere

Comment: Hi Uit, I am the developer of mobti.me . I'd love to know what your use-case is, maybe I can help. You can reach out to me via my email, mobtime AT mrbarry DOT com .

Comment: Hi there @OzBarry ! This is kinda embarrassing haha, some months ago we used mobti and people was playin' kinda unfair, so I just wanted to develop a script with not other purpose than every time someone presses the random button I could update the json with myself at the end.